# Icons not being deleted using 'objFSO.DeleteFile()'

Tags: file-io, vbscript

I have a VBScript that should delete all users desktop icons and replace them with a clean version, but for some reason it is not deleting.

If I manually delete, the icons are copied. However if I comment out the copy line, and then run the script, they are not deleted. No error occurs.

Can somebody please suggest what the problem might be?

```
'****************************************************
'* Logon Script File For Users in the DD Domain     *
'* Purpose: Ensure required icons are on desktop    *
'****************************************************

Option Explicit

Dim objFSO                  ' A File System object (for checking files/folders exist, copying, and deleting)
Dim objShell                ' A shell object (for accessing special folders)
Dim user_name               ' The user name of the currently logged in user
Dim i                       ' Dummy for looping


'****************************************************
'* Create the required desktop icons                *
'****************************************************

' Set the desktop folder location
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
desktop_location = objShell.SpecialFolders.Item("Desktop")

' Set the location where the files to copy can be found
desktop_icon_store = "\\videss\Shortcuts\Desktop\"

'Check that the users desktop location exists
If (objFSO.FolderExists(desktop_location)) Then

    ' Delete all files in the desktop folder
    objFSO.DeleteFile(desktop_location & "*.*")

    ' Copy all files to the desktop folder
    objFSO.CopyFile desktop_icon_store & "*.*", desktop_location, True

End IF


'****************************************************
'* Reset the objects and exit                       *
'****************************************************

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer here, that suddenly dawned - the trailing `\`.

Changing the code to this did the trick -

```
desktop_location = objShell.SpecialFolders.Item("Desktop") & "\"
```